# problema com jquery mask em formulário dinâmico

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom montei um formulário dinâmico onde tenho o 'input' parcelas. Ele ja com valor 1 carregado.

Tenho outro 'input' chamado valor, onde uso o jquery mask. Ele funciona porém quando altero o valor do 'input' parcelas são criados outros 'input' valor, e a mask para de funcionar.

Não tenho log de erros no console.
Segue me código:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.valores').mask('00.000.000,00', {
                reverse: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Isso ai não tem jeito, você vai ter que rodar a função toda vez que adicionar um novo input, tenta trocar o `$(document).ready` por `$(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {`. Vê se da certo...

Comment: Deu certo da sua forma.

Comment: Beleza, vou postar a resposta pra oficializar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você vai ter que carregar a função toda vez que adicionar um input (modificar o DOM), para isso use o `$(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){  });`:

```
<script>
    $(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
        $('.valores').mask('00.000.000,00', {
            reverse: true
        });
    });
</script>
```